# Chrysler Sebring 2007 Hvac

Tags: hvac, chrysler, sebring

My Ride Chrysler Sebring 2007 Driving side AC is blowing hot air while passangr side is cold. Any theories?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sounds like the blend door actuator for one side or the other is not functioning. When you change from hot to cold, does either side change with it? If neither side changes, you need to replace both. If one side changes, the other side needs to be changed.

Comment: Another thing to check is if the freon is low.  Some vehicles have shown the symptom of cold on the passenger side while warm on the driver side.  If this is the case, you should still hear a change in sound of the airflow when selecting hot to cold.  If no sound change, then I would be following @Paulster2 direction of a possible blend door actuator fault.

Comment: Sometimes this can be fixed with an actuator recalibration.